# How I can define this operator in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, operators

I want to define an operator $G$ such that

$$G(f):=\begin{cases}f(\{x\}),&\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is even}\\\frac1{f(\{x\})},&\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

for any function $f$, where $\{x\}$ means "fractional part of $x$". I dont have a clue about how to do this. I wanted to write something like

```
G[2 + Sin[x]]
```

that define the above over the function $f(x)=2+\sin x$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
g[f_][x_?NumericQ] := If[EvenQ@Floor[x], f@FractionalPart[x], 1/f@FractionalPart[x]]
```

The `?NumericQ` part is important because `EvenQ` returns `False` immediately for anything that is not a number.

In this case, `f` needs to be an actual *function*.  `Sin[x]` and `Sin[x]+2` are not functions. They are expressions in terms of `x`.  `Sin` and `Sin[#]+2&` are functions. Look up [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) to see what `#` and `&` mean.

Example:

```
g[Sin][5/2]
(* Sin[1/2] *)
```

Comment: I know how to build pure functions. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Masacroso Great! I was not sure, so I mentioned it just in case. In your post you show an expression like `2+Sin[x]` instead of a function. If you have an expression like that, normally you also need to specify the variable, `x`.  That's how `Plot`, `Integrate`, etc. work.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Szabolcs' answer I would sugest a different approach, that quite literally follows the mathematical definition of $G(f)$. Note that we may avoid the premature evaluation of any argument that is not numeric by using [`Divisible`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible.html) instead of [`EvenQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvenQ.html) or [`OddQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OddQ.html):

```
g[ f_Function ] := Function[ x, 
    Piecewise[
        {
          {     f[ FractionalPart @ x ],       Divisible[ Floor[x], 2 ] },
          { 1 / f[ FractionalPart @ x ], Not @ Divisible[ Floor[x], 2 ] }
        },
        Indeterminate (* in all other cases *)
    ]
]
```

We may then use this for numeric arguments:

```
f = Function[ x, 2 + Sin[x] ];
h = g[f]; (* or directly g[f] @ x *)
h[ 5/2 ]
```

> $2 + \text{Sin}[\frac{1}{2}]$

In the given form we can now also work symbolically:

```
h[x] // Head
```

> Piecewise