# Symbollic integration and differentiation of operated functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators

This question is a continuation of [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145685/how-i-can-define-this-operator-in-mathematica).

I used the answer provided in the previous question to write this code

```
g[f_][x_?NumericQ] := If[EvenQ@Floor[x], f@FractionalPart[x], 1/f@FractionalPart[x]]
```

for an arbitrary pure function $f$. It works for many things but it cannot be integrated or differentiated properly. One example: this code

```
Integrate[g[1 + Sin[Pi #] &][x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

stay unevaluated. If I use instead `NIntegrate` I can get a numerical result. But Im interested in the symbolic result. In the same way this code

```
g[1 + Sin[Pi #] &]'[3]
```

stay unevaluated. Of course this code doesnt work also

```
Plot[D[g[1 + Sin[Pi #] &][x], x], {x, 0, 2}, Exclusions -> {Sin[2 Pi x] == 0}]
```

In short: I dont know how to differentiate or integrate these operated functions. Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: For one sub-issue with plotting derivatives, start here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35355/plot-dsinx-and-evaluate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using [`EvenQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvenQ), which always evaluates to a boolean, I would use something like [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod), which remains unevaluated for non-numeric arguments:

```
g[f_][x_] := If[Mod[Floor[x], 2] == 0,
    f@FractionalPart[x],
    1/f@FractionalPart[x]
]
```

Then:

```
expr = g[1 + Sin[π #] &][x]
Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> If[Mod[Floor[x], 2] == 0, (1 + Sin[π #1] &)[
>     FractionalPart[x]], 1/(1 + Sin[π #1] &)[FractionalPart[x]]]
>
> (4 + π)/π

Comment: It works for me in M9, M10.3 and M11.1. Maybe you should try from a fresh kernel?

Comment: right, it seems to work now.

Comment: Indeed I see that, in my previous code, if I quit the `_NumericQ` part it work as expected.

Comment: @Masacroso Generally, I begin all function definitions with things like `ClearAll[g]`.